# Using Make Grids and Graticules Layer in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, grids-graticules

I'm trying to use the Make Grids and Graticules Layer tool in ArcMap  (have a ArcInfo license).   I'm looking for a basic example like in North America.

eg.

1. Start with empty map
2. Set data frame to  NAD83 UTM Zone 1N
3. Create File geodatabase
4. Create GridExample dataset in FGDB in NAD83 UTM Zone 1N
5. Open; Make Grids and Graticules Layer tool

   - Select grid template C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\GridTemplates\Quad_24K_NAD83.xml
   - Select Extent, and Same as Display from drop down list
     this sets Left: -5620263.767724, Top: -5620263.767724, Right: -5620263.767724, Bottom: -5620263.767724
   - Select the GridExample dataset in FGDB for Input Feature Dataset
   - Output layer is set automatically to Quad_24K_NAD83
6. Run the tool

Output is as follows, but fails to create the grid.  Creates the feature classes ok.   **Can anyone hint on improving this example to create the grid?**

> Executing: MakeGridsAndGraticulesLayer "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\GridTemplates\Quad_24K_NAD83.xml"
>   "-5620263.767724 -5275836.261749 5621263.767724 5276836.261749"
>   C:\data\FGDB\Grids.gdb\Grid1 Quad_24K_NAD83 Quad_24K_NAD83 24000
>   -3.18645767674729E-04 "3 Centimeters" "2 Meters" PROJCS['GCS NAD 1983 CORS96 UTM Zone 60N
>   (Calculated)',GEOGCS['GCS_NAD_1983_CORS96',DATUM['D_NAD_1983_CORS96',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',177.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]];IsHighPrecision
>   NO_CONFIGURELAYOUT
>   "PROJCS['NAD_1983_StatePlane_Hawaii_1_FIPS_5101',GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983',DATUM['D_North_American_1983',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-155.5],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9999666666666667],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',18.83333333333333],UNIT['Meter',1.0]];-5123000
>   -12084900 10000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;0.001;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision"
>   "GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983',DATUM['D_North_American_1983',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]];-400
>   -400 1000000000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;8.98315284119521E-09;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision" # # Start
>   Time: Tue May 08 16:46:56 2012
>
> The area-of-interest is much larger than the grid's intended area.
>   Processing time may be long. Failed to create features in GRD_Grid1.
>   Failed to execute (MakeGridsAndGraticulesLayer).

Comment: It appears your scale/extent is too small for the xml template.  Try zooming in more if you can, or you can may also use the built in Grids and Graticules Wizard, http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s90000000t000000.htm

Answer (score 1):

I run into these types of problems when **another process has locked the geodatabase.**

Try close all instances of ArcMap and ArcCatalog and make sure no other ArcMap processes are running (On some machines ArcGIS processes stay open even after the application has been closed)

See [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15834/why-do-arcmap-exe-processes-stay-open-after-i-close-arcmap) for more on ArcMap.exe processes staying open after closing ArcMap